# Display Text not updating from "Changing" event for CheckedComboboxEdit

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

I have a CheckedComboBox that has a "None" item in it that when selected should unselect any other checkboxes and if you select any of the other checkboxes it should unselect "None".

I was trying to accomplish this in the EditValueChanging Event and had partial success.  I was intercepting the event's `e.NewValue` and setting it accordingly.
The underlying Value is being set but the Text displayed by the control is showing old values still.

If you click in the control a second time and click back out it updates the display....

I have tried calling Refresh(), Update(), Invalidate().  What am I missing?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
void combo_onSelectedIndexchanged 
{
   if (combo.SelectedItem == "None") UncheckAllBoxes();
}

void check_onCheckedChanged 
{
   if (check.checked && combo.selectedItem == "None") combo.SelectedItem = 0;
}
```

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't believe I can access the event of a cell in my checkedcomboboxedit that is populated programmatically.

Comment: Looks like I got confused what your question was. Are you using this? 
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CheckedCombobox-Control-52dbdb37/sourcecode?fileId=74384&pathId=403904509   
If this is the case, this code will not fit

Comment: I am using something similar to that.  A DevExpress product.